# PHP Pull from database, convert to XML and append to existing XML document

Tags: php, xml, symfony-2.3

I'm trying to add to one *SimpleXMLElement* from another one, but I get the error:

> Warning: SimpleXMLElement::addChild(): Cannot add child. Parent is not a permanent member of the XML tree

```
$xml = $Global->serializeTradeShowTable();
$xmlDeser = simplexml_load_string($xml);

$doc = simplexml_load_file($path);
$tradeshows = $doc->Tradeshows;

foreach($xmlDeser->item as $item)
{

    $name = (string)$item->friendlyName;
    $formatted_name = str_replace(' ', '_', $name);

    $sxe = new \SimpleXMLElement("<option></option>");
    $sxe->addAttribute('name', $formatted_name);
    $sxe->addAttribute('value', $name);
    $sxe[0] = $name;

    $tradeshows->addChild($sxe);

}
```

I'm not sure why I can't pass one type of *SimpleXMLElement* to another. Is some type of namespacing required? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please show examples of both XML and desired result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a couple of problems.  The first which is causing the main error is, I believe, a problem with the line...

```
$tradeshows = $doc->Tradeshows;
```

You need to check that this is giving you the node your expecting.  If your document is (for example)

```
<Tradeshows>
</Tradeshows>
```

Then $tradeshows should be just

```
$tradeshows = $doc;
```

But without the actual XML, it's difficult to tell.  But this is where you should be able to correct the ' Parent is not a permanent member ' bit.

Secondly, `addChild` takes the name of the element and optionally the value.  You are trying to add an SimpleXMLElement in.  If you change your code there to...

```
foreach($xmlDeser->item as $item)
{
    $name = (string)$item->friendlyName;
    $formatted_name = str_replace(' ', '_', $name);

    $newElement = $tradeshows->addChild("option");
    $newElement->addAttribute('name', $formatted_name);
    $newElement->addAttribute('value', $name);
}
```

This should add the `<option>` in and then set the attributes.

Comment: Thanks, this was helpful. In the first case, there were two Tradeshow nodes, so `$doc->Tradeshows` was not returning what I expected. I changed it to `$doc->en->Tradeshows` and got what I wanted. 

In the second case your code worked perfectly, thank you.